# How to convert binary data into an image in matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm using the following code to convert an image into binary form.

```
% lets suppose that the name of image file is caption with an extension .jpg
X=imread('caption.jpg');
g=reshape((dec2bin(typecast(X(:),'uint8'),8)-'0').',1,[])
```

After running the code, I'm getting 1xn matrix of type double, having a series of 0's and 1's.

Now I want to convert this matrix `g` back into an image.

The converted image should be similar to caption.jpg.

Comment: So... `reshape` it back to the original size and use `imwrite`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need the number of rows and number of cols in the initial image to get the color image back.

```
rowsize = size(X,1);
colsize = size(X,2);
final_image = uint8(reshape(bi2de(reshape(g,8,[])',2,'left-msb'),rowsize,colsize,[]));
imwrite(final_image,'caption.jpg');
```

Comment: by the way, the edit u've told me, i'd tried it but don't know y it wasn't working.. but let me check it again one more time.. anyways thanks alot mr.nishant :)

Comment: the changes u've told me, i'd already did it, but i've tried it once again.. still the same problem. the fucntion bin2im with the changes is still returning a black and white image. please try to sort out the problem nd if u find it, do let me know it nd let me know the solution too.. thanks again :)

Comment: please add your code in the question in a well formatted way

Comment: % this is the code for bin2im which is giving me the black n white image, not the coloured image. after making the changes u've told me, the problem still prevails.

function [] = bin2im(bin_vector,rows,cols)

g=bin_vector;

rowsize = rows;
colsize = cols;
final_image = uint8(reshape(bi2de(reshape(g,8,[])',2,'left-msb'),rowsize,colsize,[]));
imwrite(final_image,'recovered image.jpg');

imshow('recovered image.jpg')

end

Comment: This function is working fine on my machine ,please restart your matlab instance and recheck it

Comment: is this the compiler's issue? becoz i've tried it alot of times, still the same issue. em using matlab r2009b

Comment: I am not sure about it , but if it is working fine on the terminal , then It should not be , BTW I am using matlab 2011b.If what you posted is just a part of the function then I would suggest posting the whole function, and please add the code in the question , **DO NOT ADD FULL CODE IN COMMENT**

Comment: well thanks mr.nishant, i don't know what was the problem, but it has started working properly, the same code which was creating problems yesterday is working absolutely fine now without any changes. :)
thanks alot for helping me :)

Comment: @haseebqureshi If you think this answer is good then choose it as best answer , so that others coming here will know what to do. :)

Comment: @nihant, yar i've joined stackoverflow just a few days ago, lemme know  how can i choose this answer as the best answer, i'll do it :)

Comment: You will be seeing a check tick box near my answer, click on it :)

Comment: well mr.@nishant, i need your help on few more things nd u've helped me alot on my this question. can i've ur facebook or skype i.d, i want to ask few things more from u.. my facebook i.d is: haseeb12388@live.com
em waiting for an encouraging reply from u..

Comment: actually there are only 2 days left in my final year project's presentation, nd em still left wiht password nd image proection phase for my fyp. so i need ur help. if i can get ur skype nd facebook i.d, it'll be helpful to me, as i'll explain the thing more briefly to you on skype or facebook video calling. waiting for your encouraging reply :)

Comment: I am sorry , but my hands are quite full with a current project ,Already It's difficult to take out time for this site so sorry I cannot give you contact information, But you can still ask your questions on this site , I am quite sure either I or somebody else will respond to your questions . :)

Comment: ok no problem :)
this is a link for my other question that i've asked rit now. have a look at it :)
hope, u'll be able to help me :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24219418/how-can-i-make-my-file-image-nd-password-protected-in-matlab

Comment: sorry ,I have looked at it , but I have not the slightest clue how to do it, I am myself a beginner in matlab,